# Confirmation message before saving data in remix js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I have an `Action` function inside my `saveData.tsx` Remix App, which saves some data inside database table. This is the file

```
import type { ActionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Form, useActionData } from "@remix-run/react";
import React from "react";
import { saveData } from "~/models/data.server";

export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
    // do some work, collect the `result` which is a JSON.. and then
await saveData(result);
return redirect (`/to/somePath`);
}

export default function Index() {
 const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();

 return(
  <div>
    <Form method="post">
     <button type="submit">Upload data</button>
    </Form>
  </div>  
 );
}
```

So what I really want to do is, I want to have a confirm message before `await saveData(result)` . The confirm message I set it as another `tsx` file with two buttons `Save` or `Cancel` . The modal is in a different route. As an example `(/to/confirm.tsx)` . I want to call this `confirm.tsx` before saving this `await saveData(result)`. Then when I click the `Save` button from that `confirm.tsx` I want to run `await saveData(result)` and save the data to database. Vice versa I when I click `cancel` I want cancel the data saving and `redirect` to the `saveData.tsx` .

I have not used any `Action` or `Loader` functions inside the `confirm.tsx`.  This is the `confirm.tsx` file

```
export default function Confirm() {
 return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>Are you sure you want to save the data?</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Save</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```

What I intially did was, I passed the `result` in to `URL` as string like this without using `await saveData(result)` inside the `Action` function of `saveData.tsx`

```
export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
    // do some work, collect the `result` which is a JSON.. and then
    // await saveData(result); <= did not used save functioin inside this file
return redirect(`/to/${JSON.stringify(result)}/confirm`)
}
```

I used the `confirm.tsx` route as this previously `/to/$data/confirm`

Then inside the `confirm.tsx` I used an `Action` function. Inside that `Action` function I got the `jsonString` using `params`. Then `JSON.pares` ed the `jsonString` and passed that object to `await saveData(jsonParsedData)`. Then after saving the data, redirected to previous route `saveData.tsx` like below.

```
import type { ActionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Form, useActionData } from "@remix-run/react";
import React from "react";
import { saveData } from "~/models/data.server";

export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
  const jsonString = params.data;
  const jsonParsedData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  await saveData(jsonParsedData);
  return redirect(`/to/saveData`);
}

export default function Confirm() {
 return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>Are you sure you want to save the data?</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <button>Save</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Link to={`/to/saveData`}>
       <button>Cancel</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```

This previous method works. But handling hundreds of thousands of data would not be possible that way (passing data to URL). I just need to do all the process inside a single file without passing data into another file. I just only want to control the data saving confirmation using a different `componant` or file or what ever it is.

I think I have clearly explained the issue, if it's not clear please let me know how to help it explain further more. A help would be greatly appreciated on this matter!.

Comment: Why not display the confirmation modal on the page the user is on ***prior*** to actually submitting the form and doing *some* of the work in the `action` function? Can you [edit] the post to include more details around this use case and how the UI logic should flow?

Comment: `@DrewReese` I edited the initial post and added the code snippets to give a more clear idea about what I did, Please help me on this one. Thanks so much for checking in.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not, or can't, display the modal and get confirmation from the user they want to save the data prior to submitting the form? Submitting the form is all asynchronous code, so you can't stop midstream in the `action` function and render some JSX. You'll need to either load the question to the user before starting the submission processing, or split this into separate "actions", one to submit the form and "do some work, collect the `result`", and the the other to save the data, either before or after redirecting.

Comment: I am a newbie for Remix and do not have much experience with Remix run. I would really appreciate if you could provide the code example on two suggestions that you have made.

How can I display the modal prior to submitting the form. Because on Remix we use <Form method="post" > component two wrap a <button >. when we click the button, `Action` function getting called. So as from what you said "so you can't stop midstream in the action function and render some JSX" , what I understand is we cannot render any componant inside action function.

Comment: @DrewReese So actually I want to load the question after I click the submit button. Then from their I want to control the saving part.  I think what I understand is, what best is, splitting this process into separate two actions. Could you please let me know what I understood was correct? And I would really appreciate if you could explain me how to split those two actions.

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with `remix.run` (*though pretty familiar with `react-router`*). My thoughts here are that you can return whatever the data is from the action via the [`useActionData`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/hooks/use-action-data) back to the calling component with the form, ***and then*** trigger the confirmaion modal and redirect from the component. If you want I can make an attempt at an implementation update to your `Index` component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251317/discussion-between-hashan-hemachandra-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on `@Drew`s method and found out an answer for this issue. So what I understood was, in remix, we cannot do POST requests inside page rendering part. It has to be only inside the ***action*** function. It is not possible to execute something like this inside the page rendering function in remix

```
const confirmHandler = async () => {
    await saveData(result);
    navigate("/to/saveData");
  };
```

In remix we use `buttons` inside the ***Form*** components to submit the Form using action function. While I was looking for an answer, I found this tutorial

> [Remix Single: Multiple Forms and Single Button Mutations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2i-9cYxSdc&t=25s)

Inside buttons, we can use **name** and **value** attributes. Then by checking the value of the clicked button, we can control action function on each button. Keeping that in mind, first I will return the *result* as a `json`, when the **upload data** button is clicked. To do that I am passing name and value attribute to that button.

```
<button type="submit" name="_action" value="upload">Upload data</button>
```

Then on the save button of the confirm component, I will change button type as `submit` and also add the *name* and *value* properties.

```
<button type="submit" name="_action" value="save">Save</button>
```

So inside the action function

```
export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
    // do some work, collect the `result` which is a JSON.. and then

 if (formData.get("_action") === "upload") {
   return json({ result });
 }

 if (formData.get("_action") === "save") {
   await saveData(result);
   return redirect(`/to/the/successAlert`)
 }

}
```

So the finalized Parent and Child components will be like below

***Parent component***

```
import React from "react";
import type { ActionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Form, useActionData, useTransition } from "@remix-run/react";
import { saveData } from "~/models/data.server";

export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
  // do some work, collect the `result` which is a JSON.. and then

  if (formData.get("_action") === "upload") {
   return json({ result });
  }

  if (formData.get("_action") === "save") {
   await saveData(result);
   return redirect(`/to/the/successAlert`)
  }
}

export default function Index() {
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();
  const transition = useTransition();
  const data = actionData?.result;

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false);
  const [showConfirmSave, setShowConfirmSave] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    switch(transition.state) {
      case "submitting":
        if (!submitted) {
          setSubmitted(true);
        }
        break:

      case "idle":
        if (submitted && data) {
          setShowConfirmSave(true);
        }
        break:
    }

    
  }, [data, submitted, setShowConfirmSave, setSubmitted, transition]);

  const modalHideHandler = () => {
     setShowConfirmSave(false);
  };

  return(
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="_action" value="upload">Upload data</button>
        {showConfirmSave && <Confirm modalHide={modalHideHandler} />}
      </Form>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

***Child component (confirm modal)***

```
interface Props {
  modalHide: () => void;
}

export default function Confirm({modalHide}: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Are you sure you want to save the data?</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
          <button type="submit" name="_action" value="save">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={modalHide}>Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the native alert is not enough for you Window.confirm() (I highly recommended)

```
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to save?")) {
 run this if user say yes
}
```

you can import your modal component to your page and show it conditional

the element who triggers `action` you make change an state for example:

```
const [showConfirmationModal, setShowConfirmationModal] = useState(false)
```

then you conditional render it

```
{ showConfirmationModal && <confirmModal confirmCallback={action}></confirmModal> }
```

or you can pass as a props to show

```
<confirmModal show={showConfirmationModal} confirmCallback={action}>
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the initial post with code snippets so it can be more understandable. Please help me with your answer on that

Answer (score 0):

The `action` function is asynchronous code. You can't stop in the middle of the `action` handler and render any React component. What I suspect you'll need to do is to:

1. Submit the form and process `action`, and return data to the component.
2. The `Index` component will track when the form has been submitted so that when data is returned the component can trigger the confirmation modal, handle the user response, and then issue an imperative redirect.

It might look something like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import type { ActionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Form, useActionData, useTransition } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { saveData } from "~/models/data.server";

export const action = async ({ request, params }: ActionArgs) => {
  // do some work, collect the `result`, and then
  return /* JSON data */
}

export default function Index() {
  const data = useActionData<typeof action>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const transition = useTransition();

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false);
  const [showConfirmSave, setShowConfirmSave] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    switch(transition.state) {
      case "submitting":
        if (!submitted) {
          setSubmitted(true);
        }
        break:

      case "idle":
        if (submitted && data) {
          setShowConfirmSave(true);
        }
        break:
    }

    
  }, [data, submitted, setShowConfirmSave, setSubmitted, transition]);

  const confirmHandler = async () => {
    await saveData(result);
    navigate("/to/saveData");
  };

  if (showConfirmSave) {
    return <Confirm onConfirm={confirmHandler} />
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <button type="submit">Upload data</button>
      </Form>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";

interface ConfirmProps {
  onConfirm: () => void;
}

export default function Confirm({ onConfirm }: ConfirmProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Are you sure you want to save the data?</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={onConfirm}>Save</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/to/saveData">
          <button type="button">Cancel</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have a validation inside the action function. If validation error are there, then I will return the error message with the status 400 , and if there are no any validation error, then I will return the /* JSON data */ like this =>
`if (validation) {
return json (
{
errors: {
message: validation,
},
},
{ status: 400 }
);
} else {
// do some work and
return /* JSON data */
}`

Comment: let's take /* JSON data */ as `result`
let take data as , `const data = actionData?.result`
I got the `console.log(result)` inside the `action` function

Comment: But when I try to `console.log(data)` inside the `Index()` nothing will show up. I tried using a `useEffect` also but it did not work. When I try to render something like this it'll work

`{ actionData?.result && ( <div><h3>Show Something</h3></div>)}`

Comment: But the data is not showing inside this

`const confirmHandler = async () => {
console.log(data)
await bulkUploadCodeList(data);
navigate("/codes/uploadCodeList");
};`

Comment: @Hashanhemachandra Sorry, that's a bummer. Would it be possible for you to set up a small demo of these pages and actions in a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) using the remix template?

Comment: Sure I will do that. Also I posted the current issue as another question. There is a one answer that I have to use the useSubmit() hook to do that async await. Would it be possible you to look into that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214892/is-the-action-function-only-way-to-do-the-post-request-in-remix-js/75216234#75216234) if I am not clear to you in this comment section?

Comment: @Hashanhemachandra Replied in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251317/discussion-between-hashan-hemachandra-and-drew-reese).