# Is the Action function only way to do the POST request in Remix js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I have an app where I upload a csv and I get the content of that csv as a JSON when I click the upload button. And My requirement is, I want to pause the POST request until I confirm the upload using another modal component. What I did was, I created an async await inside the UI component and passed the data returning from the Action function to that async await function `confirmHandler`. These are the methods I used from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196013/confirmation-message-before-saving-data-in-remix-js).

```
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  // Do some other work and get the csv content as a string

  const csvDataString: string = formData.get("selected_csv") as string;

  let codeListUploadValidationMessage = "";

  // Do the code list validation

  if (codeListUploadValidationMessage) {
    // if there are validation errors
    return json(
      {
        errors: {
          message: codeListUploadValidationMessage,
        },
      },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  } else {
    // if there are no any validation errors do some work convert string into an object call 'result'
    // Then return the 'result' as a JSON
    return json({ result });
  }
};

export default function Index() {
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false);
  const [showConfirmSave, setShowConfirmSave] = React.useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setData(actionData?.result)
    console.log("=== Log of data: ", data);
  }, [actionData?.result, data]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    switch (transition.state) {
      case "submitting":
        if (!submitted) {
          setSubmitted(true);
        }
        break;

      case "idle":
        if (submitted && data) {
          setShowConfirmSave(true);
        }
        break;
    }
  }, [data, submitted, setShowConfirmSave, setSubmitted, transition]);

  const confirmHandler = async () => {
    await bulkUploadCodeList(data);
    setShowConfirmSave(false);
  };

  if (showConfirmSave) {
    return <Confirm onConfirm={confirmHandler} />;
  }

return(
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <button type="submit">Upload data</button>
      </Form>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

.

So this is the `confirm` modal

```
import {
  Link,
} from "@remix-run/react";
import React from "react";

interface ConfirmProps {
  onConfirm: () => void;
}

export default function Confirm({ onConfirm }: ConfirmProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Are you sure you want to save the data?</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={onConfirm}>Save</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/codes/uploadCodeList">
          <button type="button">Cancel</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I can get the confirm modal when I click the Upload button, But that async await function not doing any POST request to the backend. How can I resolve this? A help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems action function is the only way to do the POST request, in the linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196013/confirmation-message-before-saving-data-in-remix-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) I have shown how I resolved my question. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `useSubmit()` hook. This is how you programmatically submit in Remix. So in your `onConfirm()` handler, prompt to confirm, and if *yes*, call `submit()`, otherwise `event.preventDefault()`.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-submit

Comment: Could you please give an example or how to use this `onConfirm()`